# How to prepare text for more successful "person" entity type classification when using stanford Named Entity Recognition

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford NER classification as part of a PHI De-identification process running on laboratory text notes. I am noticing that in some cases, the classification tags e.g `<PERSON></PERSON>` tags can find a person name, but then continue to tag much more text either side of the found name. This loss of precision means that we could potentially lose a lot of non-PHI and valuable info. Is there a way to prepare text in such a way that entities are more precisely discovered?